# Rails app on Heroku: Bootstrap select not opening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, view, selection, parameters

I have a Rails 4 app which works well in localhost in both dev and production mode. 
When I deploy my app to Heroku, it does load for user to sign up. But at the sign up page, select tag seems not to load params from controller. ( which is @universities )

View:

```
<%= f.select :university_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@universities,"id","name"), {include_blank: true}, {class: "form-control selectpicker show-tick inline", data: {width: 'auto'}} %>
```

Controller:

```
@universities = University.all
```

The sign up page looks like this: Clicking at the selection box does nothing.

[image]

Does anyone have similar problems like this? Thanks in advance.

Update #1: Turn out the problem is bootstrap select somehow not opening.

Comment: hi, did you migrate your database? And is it populated? Are there any universities in your production database?

Comment: Yes, I did migrate, seed, and I checked my database in heroku as well. The universities table is populated as expected.

Comment: are you sure that all necessary javascript and css is precompiled? (not sure that you need it for your ticker, but just to check)

Comment: I run this before push to heroku: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile. Is this okay?

Comment: yeah, it think so. That's what i do. What happens when you put <%= @universities.count %> right next to your ticker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working by include this following line in application.js file:

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

and these into application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

I guess this issue is related to bootstrap-sass gem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using a `collection_select`:

```
<%= f.collection_select :university_id, University.all, :id, :name %>
```